# Node Server .env file undifined in server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

The below screenshot shows my file structure in VS code. I have used `npm concurrent` to run both backend and frontend simultaneously. My problem is env file is not recognized in the server file. Please tell me what is wrong here.

[image]

**Second picture**

[image]

Comment: Can you show what's within the `env` file, and your `package.json`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the path where the `.env` file is to `dotenv` package.

Please modify the following line of code to

```js
require("dotenv").config();
```

like this:

```js
require("dotenv").config({path: "./back-end/.env"});
```

Comment: Still have the same error.

Comment: Did you install the dotenv package? Can I see the package.json file?

Comment: `{
  "name": "back-end",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.4.6",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}`

Comment: If I replaced the env file with a new place according to the second picture It worked. But I want to move that file to the back-end folder. Then how should change my path?

Comment: Oh I misunderstood the .env file's path.. I thought it was in the main folder. In that case, you can change the path to "./back-end/.env"

Answer (score 2):

write PORT in .env file in backend folder

```
PORT = <PORT_NUMBER>
```

For Ex.

```
PORT = 3000
```

Install dotenv in backend folder

```
npm i dotenv
```

Import dotenv in server.js file

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

or set .env path in

```
require("dotenv").config({path: "./back-end/.env"});
```

Then Check by:

```
console.log(process.env);
```

Run in backend folder

```
node server.js
```

Comment: Thank you I have followed these steps. But didn't work

Comment: Go into back-end folder and then run node server.js instead of node back-end/server.js

Comment: Or if you wants to run node back-end/server.js then you have to specify .env path

Answer (score 1):

To use DotEnv, first install it using the command: npm i dotenv . Then in your app, require and configure the package like this: require('dotenv'). config()

```
    require('dotenv').config();

console.log(process.env.MY_ENV_VAR);
```

Comment: I have installed `dotenv`

Comment: If I replaced the env file with a new place according to the second picture It worked. But I want to move that file to the back-end folder. Then how should change my path?